# List installed mobile provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, macos, provisioning-profile

On OSX is there any way to programmatically get the list of all iOS mobile provisioning profiles installed on the machine (that's the list you can see in XCode organizer)?.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's probably the same list, but if you look in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` you'll find the folder of provisioning profiles.  So you can just use that path to generate a list (probably with NSFileManager)

Or do a search for extension .mobileprovision

Comment: this was my first attempt, it works but it's not so smart. I would not depend on a physical path, I was looking for a solution using system calls.

Comment: this is the solution. No ways using system calls.

Comment: there's no `~/Library/MobileDevice` path on Mojave

Answer (score 31):

Command line,

**Step 1** : Open terminal and run this command to **list profiles**,

```
cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles && ls
```

or this to **open folder in finder**,

```
open ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```