# iOS Provisioning Profiles List

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I would like to know if there is a way, even if not accepted by the App Store, to programmatically have the list of the provisioning profiles installed in an iOS device. I just need to have a list of names, is it possible to have it through a directory?

I found this question: [List installed mobile provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059608/list-installed-mobile-provisioning-profiles) but is for OSX.

Thank you!

Comment: you Mean you want to see list of device installed provisioning profile.?

Comment: Yes, but programmatically, I forgot to mention it in the question. My bad.